# cannot compute principal component analysis in r

Tags: r

I am also dealing with the same problem in principal component analysis in R.The same error message is being shown:

> Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only

I have checked your answers for this, but still its not working. 
The user2662565 had the same problem.

This is the program code i have used:

```
***data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
data      
#Calculate number of rows and col
rows<-length(data[,1])
rows
cols<-length(data[1,])
cols
#Remove header and save each column to a matrix
for ( i in 1:rows){
   for ( j in 1:cols){
       if(data[i,j]=="NA"){
         data[i,j]="0"
       }
   }
}
pca_a<-princomp(data, cor=True, covmat=NULL, scores=TRUE)
#Print scree plot
require(graphics)
plot(pca_a)
#plot pca
biplot(pca_a)***
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: We have no idea what your data looks like. Run `str(data)` and copy the output. Click 'edit' on your question and paste the result.

Comment: Do your future self a favor and stop using `file.choose()`. Will you know for sure which file to choose a week, month or a year from now?

Answer (score 3):

First, you can replace `rows<-length(data[,1])` with `rows <- nrow(data)` and `cols<-length(data[1,])` with `cols <- ncol(data)`.

Second, you should provide a reproducible example by making a toy dataset. I cannot use the same data as you because `data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)` will attempt to choose a file on my computer and your data file is not on my computer. Can you make a toy dataset like `data <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)` and check if your code works?

Third, `princomp` doesn't work if any of the values of the data are non-numeric (e.g. characters). In your code, you are assigning `data[i, j] <- '0'`, which means that you are making that value of data a string of the digit `0`, not the actual number `0`. You can prevent your error by making sure that all of the values of `data` are numeric values.

Comment: I have replaced my commands.And my data had characters.Now i removed it and it worked.Thank you